# No DS in runtime in bndtools tutorial

Tags: osgi, bnd, bndtools

i follow the bndtools turtorial. On step 5, i should see 9 bundles in the runtime, including the DS bundle.
[image: The bundles i should get]

instead, i only get these bundles and the ExampleComponent does not offer the Greetings service:

[image: the bundles i got]

Does anybody know what I did wrong here?

I use Eclipse Luna
Version: Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by myself. The package org.example.impl had to be declared as a private package in provider.bnd.